# Latex on your website

Tags: latex

I am trying to build a new website from scratch. As, I would have to write mathematical and chemical expressions in the content, and I am already an avid user of physics, math and chem stack exchange websites. I would like the end product to behave similar/if possible exactly the same to the stack exchange thing.

I have no idea where to go to implement this. So, how do I implement the same type of latex editor with all the features for writing mathematical and chemical expressions in the content editor on my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding this by yourself and including it to your website might be complicated but you can use something called mathURL, check [Latex in a webpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129/embedding-latex-equations-into-a-webpage)

Comment: and for chemistry ? like chemistry.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can use MathJax, a JavaScript display engine that's what is used on chemistry.stackexchange http://www.mathjax.org/   you might use this for maths purposes aswell you may not need the first link I gave you sorry